# US International Keyboard Shortcuts not working in Outlook 16

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

US International Keyboard shortcuts, such as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (<kbd>ö</kbd>), <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> (<kbd>ü</kbd>) and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (<kbd>ß</kbd>) are not working in Outlook 16.

In Word, within Customize Ribbon, there is an option to unset keyboard shortcuts used by Office, which I did, so I have no problem using these shortcuts in Word and Excel. But in Outlook they simply do not work.

I have tried editing Group Policy as described in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/cc179143(v=office.15).

This does not work for the above mentioned shortcuts. To test whether I am doing something wrong, I tried to disable other shortcuts such as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> within the Group Poilicy Editor, and this works, so I am sure I was doing it right. Still, it has no effect on the shortcuts I need.

Any ideas? I need those shortcuts to write in German, would be a hassle to not have them. I am aware I can use <kbd>"</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> ==> <kbd>ö</kbd>, but I am VERY used to the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> combos.

Comment: A localized Office / Outlook? I'd bet they differ from any "International" version. (This is ONE of the many reasons to install English versions of Office, ONLY)

Comment: I am using an English (US) version of Windows 10, all my apps, including Outlook are in English.

Comment: Find the "help" file, look for "shortcuts" in it (i,.e. keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: How is that helpful?

Comment: You might find that your shortcuts are defined in an unexpected way.

Comment: If you are truly using the US-International keyboard (I do), you don't need all of the special possibly-masked shortcuts for non-ASCII Latin-1 characters. Instead, use the 'dead key' feature, where many of the punctuation marks double as accents. For example, to type o-umlaut (`ö`), type the double-quote key `"` immediately followed by `o`.

Comment: And how is that helpful? There is no way to unset Outlook shortcuts that I know of.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I quote my original post: "Any ideas? I need those shortcuts to write in German, would be a hassle to not have them. I am aware I can use "+o= ö, but I am VERY used to the ALT+CTRL combos."

Comment: Ah, missed "In Word, within Customize Ribbon, there is an option to unset keyboard shortcuts used by Office, which I did" - sorry for the hazzle.

Comment: You don't unset the Outlook shortcuts; you use the dead-key feature to get at the characters that are masked by the Outlook shortcuts. The entire point of the US-International layout is to make those characters accessible in a way that doesn't conflict with program shortcuts.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin well I am hoping for a response that suggests how I can use ALT+CTRL shortcuts, but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than struggle with Outlook and other applications individually,
you may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to map these keys for all of Windows.

The following example script will map these keys:

```
^!p::ö
^!y::ü
^!s::ß
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I believe this is the answer I will implement. I know AutoHotkey for gaming, never occured to me to use it in this way! Thank you very much for facilitating my daily workflow :))

Comment: Ikr?  Due to restrictions that need not be clarified (<s>such as tournament legality</s>), I find most of my AHK usage has historically been work-related rather than gaming related.  I've even used it in combo with Excel to create an automated order-entry process flow for an i3pl facility (they only offered a browser-based portal for administration) that would have otherwise required a **costly** EDI subscription.

Comment: @Arctiic that's a pretty cool use case for AHK you came up with!

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://gzipwtf.com/how-do-i-reset-keyboard-shortcuts-in-word/

> How do I reset keyboard shortcuts in Word?
>
> What to Know
>
> In Word, select the File tab. Select Options at the bottom of the left pane. Choose Customize Ribbon in the left pane.
> In the Choose commands from list, select Customize next to Keyboard Shortcuts.
> Select Reset All > Yes > Close > OK.

More:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/shortcut-keys-reset/04dfdd19-f020-4d97-9249-71c1f7692302

Additionally:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Outlook+restore+keyboard+shortcuts

Comment: Poster: "I have no problem using these shortcuts in Word and Excel. But in Outlook they simply do not work."

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, custom shortcuts are not available in Outlook. What we can do is to [create quick steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-common-or-repetitive-tasks-with-quick-steps-b184f89f-3738-4562-96de-c0244ea830f2?redirectsourcepath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fautomate-common-or-repetitive-tasks-with-quick-steps-a9caf57e-0eb0-4b48-9141-a9904da0aaf9#:%7E:text=then%20select%20OK.-,Create%20a%20Quick%20Step,-In%20Mail%2C%20select) in Outlook and assign the shortcuts suggested below.
[image]

Comment: This is a decent compromise, thank you.